# Create empty IFutureEnumerable instance

Tags: nhibernate

I have a method which performs an NHibernate query, and returns the values as an `IEnumerable<long>`. It is running a future query so the result is actually of type `IFutureEnumerable<long>`.

```
public static IEnumerable<long> GetQueryResults(IEnumerable<long> idsToFilterOn) 
{
     if((idsToFilterOn == null) || !(idsToFilterOn.Any()))
     {
         return Enumerable.Empty<long>();
     }
     else
     {
          IQueryOver<MyTable> query = GenerateTheBigQuery(idsToFilterOn);
          return query.Future<long>();
     }
}
```

I want this result to return `IFutureEnumerable<long>`, but I still want to first check the parameters, and if I know the result will be empty I want to just return an empty value without running a query.

If I just change the return type to `IFutureEnumerable<long>`, the line of code that returns `Enumerable.Empty<long>()` generates a compiler error (Cannot implicitly convert type...)

Is there some static method like `FutureEnumerable.Empty<long>()` which generates an `IFutureEnumerable` that returns an empty list?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code, there doesn't appear to be any native support for that concept. `IFutureEnumerable` is implemented by two types, one of which is deprecated and neither offer the notion of emptiness.

[image]

I suppose that leaves it up to you to create a type that implements `IFutureEnumerable<T>` that supports emptiness.